# SQL lookup/join one value in range of values

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: input tables]
These are the tables I have. I want to combine the first two table to get the third table as shown below using a query
[image: output of join]

Comment: Bhanu, please bring closure to your question, when you feel a solution has met your needs, by marking a response of your choice as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of learning SQL - try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM rates JOIN shipments ON (weight >= floor);
```

That won't get you all the way to the right answer - but I think is illustrative of how you can get there.

Answer (score 2):

Following query should get you the required resuts,

```
SELECT s.shipmentid, s.weight, r.floor, r.ceiling, r.rate 
FROM rates r 
JOIN shipments s ON s.weight <= r.ceiling and s.weight >= floor
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select
  shipments.*, 
  (select floor from rates where shipments.weight between rates.floor and rates.ceiling) as floor,
  (select ceiling from rates where shipments.weight between rates.floor and rates.ceiling) as ceiling,
  (select rate from rates where shipments.weight between rates.floor and rates.ceiling) as rate
from shipments
```

I've tested this on Access 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, I think the right syntax is:

```
SELECT s.shipmentid, s.weight, r.floor, r.ceiling, r.rate 
FROM shipments as s LEFT JOIN
     rates as r 
     ON s.weight >= r.floor AND s.weight <= r.ceiling;
```